# Can't draw to a pictureBox in a loop

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Point>` where Point contains X and Y.

What i want is to loop a list like that and draw a line point to point, i do so by:

```
foreach (List<Point> wps in map.waypoints)
{
  System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
  myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
  System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

  Point startPos = new Point(wps[0].X, wps[0].Y);

  foreach (Point p in wps)
  {
    formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, startPos.X, startPos.Y, p.X, p.Y);
    startPos = p;
  }

  myPen.Dispose();
  formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

BUT nothing gets drawn! I did the same with the on_click event to the pictureBox but instead if a looping some Points ive just used mouse X and Y. I have verified the lists of points that they dont contain rubish :D

Comment: Sorry it is still early here but why are you disposing formGraphics? It is the graphics of the picturebox

Comment: I found the error (or a solution). I was drawing on a empty pictureBox. But when i drew on a pictureBox WITH a image it all showed perfectly :D

Comment: You are doing this fundamentally wrong.  Minimize your window and restore it: gone.  Rajesh showed you how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your code in the paint event ,so that it will referesh . picturebox.Invalidate() will call the Paint() .

```
     private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       Pen pen = new Pen(Color.AliceBlue);
        PointF p = new PointF();
     e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen,p.X,p.Y);

    }
```

it suits for your code

```
      private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
   { 
         System.Drawing.Pen myPen; 
            myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        foreach (List<Point> wps in map.waypoints)
        {  
            Point startPos = new Point(wps[0].X, wps[0].Y);  
            foreach (Point p in wps)  
            {      
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, startPos.X, startPos.Y, p.X, p.Y);
                startPos = p;  
            }   
        } 
}
```

if you want to draw the line in somefunction say

```
       public void DoFunction()
       { 
         .....
         .....
         pictureBox1.Invalidate() /* here automatic call to pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) */

         . . . . 

         }
```

got it?

Comment: @janson : here i gave my own code to explain it only.change it as per your requirement

Comment: How do i use e.Graphics.DrawLine(...)? e is not defined

Comment: you have the parameter (PaintEventArgs e) in pictureBox1_Paint().check it

Comment: added the event: this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint); and then void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) on the implemntations

Comment: select the Picturebox control in UI  and right click it.go to Properties Menu->Events->Paint->doubleclick it.then write your code in pictureBox1_Paint event (refer my post above).then call the pictureBox1.invalidate()(this calls the paint event)

Comment: if you want to drawthe line in somefunction say DoFunction() {  ...                                                                 ...                                                                 pictureBox1.Invalidate()

Answer (score 1):

And don't forget to call pictureBox1.Invalidate() or pictureBox1.Refresh(), to be sure the paint event gets called.